# ClassCastException with Lucene

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search, glassfish-4.1

I´m working on a web application with Hibernate Search using Lucene. I updatetd this application to Hibernate 5.5.1 (former 4.3.5 (hibernate-core ) 4.3.10 (hibernate-entity-manager).

I´ve created an lucene index (version 4.7) with the former application. And I think the problem is maybe the older index version.

When I try to deploy my application I get the following stacktrace:

```
Schwerwiegend:   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.forName(PostingsFormat.java:112)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40Codec.<init>(Lucene40Codec.java:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:67)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:45)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder.<clinit>(Codec.java:47)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.forName(Codec.java:113)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCodec(SegmentInfos.java:469)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:361)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:53)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:50)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:731)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:50)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:63)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.readerFactory(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:131)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider$PerDirectoryLatestReader.<init>(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:206)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.createReader(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:108)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.initialize(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:91)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.PropertiesParseHelper.createDirectoryBasedReaderProvider(PropertiesParseHelper.java:172)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createIndexReader(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:224)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:109)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:256)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:513)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManagers(IndexManagerHolder.java:482)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:91)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:358)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117)
at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:541)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40PostingsFormat
at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.next(SPIClassIterator.java:141)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:65)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat$Holder.<clinit>(PostingsFormat.java:49)... 85 more
Schwerwiegend:   Exception while preparing the app
Schwerwiegend:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.forName(PostingsFormat.java:112)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40Codec.<init>(Lucene40Codec.java:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:67)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:45)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder.<clinit>(Codec.java:47)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.forName(Codec.java:113)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCodec(SegmentInfos.java:469)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:361)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:53)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:50)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:731)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:50)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:63)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.readerFactory(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:131)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider$PerDirectoryLatestReader.<init>(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:206)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.createReader(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:108)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.initialize(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:91)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.PropertiesParseHelper.createDirectoryBasedReaderProvider(PropertiesParseHelper.java:172)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createIndexReader(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:224)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:109)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:256)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:513)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManagers(IndexManagerHolder.java:482)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:91)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:358)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117)
at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:541)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class     org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40PostingsFormat
at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.next(SPIClassIterator.java:141)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:65)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat$Holder.<clinit>(PostingsFormat.java:49)
... 85 more

Schwerwiegend:   Exception while preparing the app
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40PostingsFormat
at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.next(SPIClassIterator.java:141)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:65)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat$Holder.<clinit>(PostingsFormat.java:49)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.forName(PostingsFormat.java:112)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40Codec.<init>(Lucene40Codec.java:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:67)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:45)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder.<clinit>(Codec.java:47)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.forName(Codec.java:113)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCodec(SegmentInfos.java:469)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:361)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:53)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:50)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:731)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:50)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:63)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.readerFactory(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:131)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider$PerDirectoryLatestReader.<init>(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:206)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.createReader(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:108)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.SharingBufferReaderProvider.initialize(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:91)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.PropertiesParseHelper.createDirectoryBasedReaderProvider(PropertiesParseHelper.java:172)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createIndexReader(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:224)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:109)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:256)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:513)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManagers(IndexManagerHolder.java:482)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:91)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:358)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117)
at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:541)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think I might have to upgrade the old index to get it to work? May someone help me out in this situation?

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<!-- Hibernate Configuration -->
<persistence-unit name="ZerrendaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/zerrendadb</jta-data-source>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>

  <!-- Hibernate Search Configuration -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/var/lucene/indexes"/>
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.scope" value="transaction"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.execution" value="sync"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.backend" value="lucene"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.reader.strategy" value="shared"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.erroer_handler" value="log"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.lucene_version" value="5.3.1"/>
  <property name="hibernate.search.analyzer" value="customanalyzer"/>
</properties>
```

[image: Dependencies]

EDIT1:

I updated the older lucene Versions in Netbeans and in jdk1.8.0_66 folder.
Now Netbeans gives me an error which says the following:

```
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: C:\Program Files\Java\NetBeans 8.1\java\modules\ext\maven\lucene-core-3.6.2.jar does not exist, # of retries 0
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: file C:\Program Files\Java\NetBeans 8.1\java\modules\ext\maven exists. # of retries 0
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: C:\Program Files\Java\NetBeans 8.1\java\modules\ext\maven is directory and contains: [indexer-artifact-5.1.1.jar, indexer-core-5.1.1-patched.jar, jdom-1.0.jar, lucene-core-5.3.1.jar, lucene-highlighter-3.6.2.jar, maven-dependency-tree-2.0.jar, rootpackage]
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: Cannot open C:\Program Files\Java\NetBeans 8.1\java\modules\ext\maven\lucene-core-3.6.2.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\NetBeans 8.1\java\modules\ext\maven\lucene-core-3.6.2.jar (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
```

Looks like it is searching for the older jar files? Do I have to update something else?

I also found out, that Netbeans is loading hundreds of modules including.

```
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
org.netbeans.libs.lucene/3 [3.18.1 201510222201]
org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene/2 [2.34.1.1 1 201510222201]
```

How can I turn the module loading off? Maybe this causes the error?

Comment: Are you having several versions of the Lucene libraries on your classpath by any chance? The class cast exception makes me suspicous of that.

Comment: Hi.

Edited my first post. Still getting some errors. I think Netbeans Modules might be the problem. How can I turn them off?

Comment: What are you doing to produce this error, run some tests from within the IDE? Indeed the Lucene 3.6.2 JARs look troublesome, they should not end up on the runtime classpath of your application. Have you tried building your project and run the tests on the command line (seems you use Maven)?

Comment: I´m trying to deploy my project on Glassfish 4.1.1 server. I´m not that much into running tests in command line. Don´t even know how exactly I should do this. Yes I´m using Maven. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and I'm a little desperate. You find the problem? My question I have it here [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259793/classcastexception-lucene40postingsformat-on-hibernate-search)

Comment: No sorry. I didn´t fix it. I´m still using an pretty outdated version of hibernate search... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your library versions are desynchronized.
You probably have various parts of Lucene on the classpath with different versions.

I ran into this as well after building app modules separatedly with different versions of Lucene as dependencies (due to upstream changes). After rebuilding everything, this exception disappeared.